# Add error message if I accidently type same value as my unique field before inserting

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, formula

can I do that?

I have a custom field ExternalID__c on custom object Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__c..
i created workflow to update the externalID everytime the parent .. (Master_Visit_Plan__c) create new record based on location,period,and PIC name..

I want to add error if I accidently type duplicate value before inserting..
The workflow works well, I cant save duplicate value, but I need some error popup to describe what happen

Using trigger???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write trigger for checking duplicates,You are not getting "Popup",you will get page message

Already a lot of posts are available for duplicate triggers

check below links

https://success.salesforce.com/apex/answers?id=9063A000000DazuQAC

[Trying to create a trigger to prevent creation of duplicate accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/trying-to-create-a-trigger-to-prevent-creation-of-duplicate-accounts)