# Inserting duplicate contacts not causing `DuplicateError`

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

I'm trying to insert duplicate contacts inside this test method to cause a `DuplicateError`, however the call to `Datebase.insert(duplicateContact, false)` succeeds without errors. I *want* the error. I'm following this page in the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DuplicateError.htm. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@isTest
public static void testDuplicate() {
    Test.StartTest();

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.firstname = 'dupe';
    contact.lastname = 'dupe';
    contact.email = 'test@test.com';
    insert contact;

    Contact duplicateContact = new Contact(firstname='dupe', lastname='dupe', email='test@test.com');
    Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(duplicateContact, false);

    for(Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
        if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
          // do something here.. 
        }
    }

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you enabled duplicate management ? Or any trigger written to find duplicate record ?

Comment: @PremAnandh Enable duplicate management.. hmm. I don't know. How is that done with Apex?

Comment: Okay. You can find two way whether the record is duplicate or not. 1. By using Trigger and Duplicate management by using configuration. Then only your logic will work here, without any performance Salesforce will not find dulicate records.

Comment: So both records get created in system? Check you might getting some other error

Comment: @TusharSharma Both records are created. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

As per your clarification, you have to write trigger or duplicate management configuration to find the contact record is duplicate or not.

As of now Salesforce will not throw duplicate error automatically until you perform duplicate operation.

You can use Name or email Id or Phone filed to find duplicate records( depends on your requirement)

Comment: This is precisely what I'm trying to do, but with the error: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DuplicateError.htm

Comment: Create  duplicate management and add conditions based on your requirement and activate it. Once you done this create two contact records with same details.

Comment: I can't use the declarative interface, I need to do this from Apex. It's for a package. Conditions may vary instance to instance, and I need this test to pass regardless of the environment.

Comment: Then you have to write for Apex trigger to find duplicate.

Comment: I didn't understand, Do you want to write duplicate rule via apex?

Comment: Yes, if I need to define the rule, it must be in Apex.

Comment: Why you can't create Apex Trigger to find duplicate record? It's simple

Comment: I specifically need to return `DuplicateError`. I need to pass it into a method. Also, this is legacy code. I'm trying not to add side-effects. I just need the test coverage.

Comment: Do you want to return the record if it's duplicated?

Comment: I'll need to do something like this: `Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = ((Database.DuplicateError)duplicateError).getDuplicateResult(); `.

Comment: I am not sure how you arrived that you should only use "DuplicateResult" for your test class and no other ways to get the coverage. Either your Production Org should have the Duplicate rule enabled and the other test classes having the same way to cover your classes and somehow the sandbox you are working doesn't have one enabled. 
***DuplicateResult*** class would only work if Duplicate rules are enabled in an Org.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some important steps while using that code. As per docs

> Contains information about an error that occurred when an attempt was
>   made to save a duplicate record. Use if your organization has set up
>   duplicate rules, which are part of the Duplicate Management feature.

You first need to setup [duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) to use this class. As of now it doesn't look like you have setup this that why you are not getting proper error messages. As of now, Salesforce doesn't prevent duplicates unless you enable duplicate rules.

You can also follow this trailhead: [Resolve and Prevent Duplicate Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management/units/sales_admin_duplicate_management_unit_2)

You can also use trigger to setup this. But that's not an easy part in your use case as you have multiple orgs with different conditions. So I suggest you check duplicate rules they will surely help you.

Comment: Standard contact matching rules are activated by default. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_standard_contact_rule.htm&type=5. If I understand correctly, this should result with a `DuplicateError` due to the `OR (First Name AND Last Name AND Email)` rule.

Comment: @shmuli they are not activated they are just created. You can use them but first, you need to enable them.

Comment: The docs read: "The standard contact [..] matching rules identify duplicate contacts [..]. They’re activated by default." Also, I'm looking for a way to do this with Apex.

Comment: @shmuli then verify someone might disabled them. To do this in apex you need to write your own logic. This will help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/trying-to-create-a-trigger-to-prevent-creation-of-duplicate-accounts

Comment: A trigger isn't gonna do the trick. I specifically need the `DuplicateError`, since I'll be using it for this: `Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = ((Database.DuplicateError)duplicateError).getDuplicateResult(); `.

Comment: @shmuli then duplicate rule is only option for you. Check if you have configured them correctly. Share screenshots of UI.